# AVAudioPlayer not playing iPad2

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4, avaudioplayer

New to IOS dev, I'm testing AVAudioplayer to play sound on iPad2 (Xcode 4.2 project,  ARC/storyboard enabled). Sound plays ok in simulator and no error. No error on device either but no sound.

Been browsing this fine resource temple, but nothing I've tried based on feedback here has produced anything but deafening iPad silence. Could someone help? My .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    UISlider *volumeControl;
    UILabel *timerLabel;
    NSTimer *playbackTimer;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *volumeControl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *timerLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *playbackTimer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
-(IBAction) playAudio;
-(IBAction) stopAudio;
-(IBAction) adjustVolume;
@end
```

My .m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize volumeControl, timerLabel, playbackTimer, audioPlayer;

-(void)playAudio
{
    playbackTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(updateTime)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:YES];
    [audioPlayer play];
}

-(void)stopAudio
{
    [playbackTimer invalidate];
    [audioPlayer stop];
}
-(void)adjustVolume
{
    if (audioPlayer != nil)
    {
        audioPlayer.volume = volumeControl.value;
    }
} 

-(void)updateTime
{
    float minutes = floor(audioPlayer.currentTime/60);
    float seconds = audioPlayer.currentTime - (minutes * 60);

    float duration_minutes = floor(audioPlayer.duration/60);
    float duration_seconds = 
    audioPlayer.duration - (duration_minutes * 60);

    NSString *timeInfoString = [[NSString alloc] 
                                initWithFormat:@"%0.0f.%0.0f / %0.0f.%0.0f",
                                minutes, seconds, 
                                duration_minutes, duration_seconds];

    timerLabel.text = timeInfoString;
}


-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:
(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
}
-(void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:
(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error
{
}
-(void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player
{
}
-(void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player
{
}
```

my viewDidLoad:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                             pathForResource:@"song"
                                             ofType:@"mp3"]];

        NSError *error;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                       initWithContentsOfURL:url
                       error:&error];
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@", 
                  [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            audioPlayer.delegate = self;
            [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
        }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the file is indeed an mp3 format. Make sure that you are copying the file into the bundle, and not playing off of local path on your desktop. Check the device volume. Check the return BOOL from the play call. all of these are possible explanations.

Comment: Yep, file is definitely mp3, file in bundle, device volume max, but despite start button properly linked in IB cant get log returned on either didstartplaying or didfinishplaying?

Comment: try restarting the simulator / device. sometimes when the audio has changed, like for example while using an app like Boom this could happen.

Comment: so what of the above things was it?

Answer (score 0):

Is it not playing sounds at all? No sounds even with headphones plugged in? If it's just no sound through the built-in speaker, but sounds through headphones, make sure that your device ring/sounds volume isn't muted. Check the toggle switch on the side (if you have that set to mute vs orientation lock). The bell shouldn't be crossed out. Just because you press the volume up button doesn't mean it's unmuted from the speaker. Have you tested YouTube videos or music files to ensure your iPad isn't having hardware issues?